# how to fetch data from firestore array of a document with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

this is my users collection in cloud fire store:

[users collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3JET.png)

this is the function that gets users from users collection in firestore

```
 Stream<QuerySnapshot> fetchUsersInSearch() {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
  }
```

i use this method

```
  final emailResults = snapshot.data.documents
              .where((u) => u['email'].contains(query));
```

in the following streamBuilder to fetch users by their email.

i have this streamBuilder to populate the data on screen

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: DatabaseService().fetchUsersInSearch(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

          final emailResults = snapshot.data.documents
              .where((u) => u['email'].contains(query));

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          if (emailResults.length > 0) {
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: ListView(
                children: emailResults
                    .map<Widget>((u) => GestureDetector(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.1),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  border: Border(
                                      bottom: BorderSide(
                                          width: 0.3, color: Colors.grey[50]))),
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                        backgroundImage:
                                            NetworkImage(u['userAvatarUrl']),
                                        radius: 20,
                                      ),
                                title: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(u['email'],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              color: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .accentColor),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 5,
                                      ),
                                
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            showUserProfile(u['id']);
                          },
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No results found',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
```

this is working perfectly and fetching users inside a listView by their email...

p.s: the (query) is a string i type in a seach bar.

how can i make a query to fetch users by their otherUsernames...the second field in the screenshot of the users collection ?!

i tried this:

```
  final otherUsernamesResults = snapshot.data.documents
              .where((u) => u['otherUsernames'].contains(query));
```

but its returning this error:

```
The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains("#username1")
```

what am i doing wrong here ?!!

any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUsers() {
  final usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  return usersCollection.where('otherUsernames', arrayContainsAny: ['username1', 'username2']);
}
```

For firestore version 0.16.0

Comment: i made some corrections to your answer to make it work:

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUsers() {
  final usersCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
  return usersCollection.where('otherUsernames', arrayContainsAny: ['username1', 'username2']);
}

but at least the the approach made me happy that we can search for users by sub collections